# Column level vs table level constraints in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

a.       Column Level

```
GO

CREATE TABLE Products
(
ProductID INT CONSTRAINT pk_products_pid PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName VARCHAR(25)
);

GO
```

b.      Table Level

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
ProductID INT,
ProductName VARCHAR(25),
CONSTRAINT pk_products_pid PRIMARY KEY(ProductID)
);
GO
```

Is their any difference between Column level and table level constraints?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. It's just a matter of personal taste how you apply the constraint.

The primary key constraint is just a primary key constraint - it always applies to the **table** (after all: it could contain multiple columns - it cannot be "at the column level").

It's not "at the column level" once or at the "table level" in the other case - it's the same always.

Just for fun - you can also create the primary key constraint a third way:

```
(CREATE TABLE statement)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Products
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Products_pid PRIMARY KEY(ProductID)
```

and that again would be identical to the two other options you already have.

Answer (score 10):

Your first example declares the constraint **in line**, the second does not. Only **simple** keys (involve one attribute) can be declared in line, **compound** keys (involving multiple columns) cannot. But both are **table-level** constraints!

---

There are four logical levels of constraint:

1) Column level:

```
CHECK ( ProductID > 0 )
```

2) Row level:

```
CHECK ( Product_start_date < Product_end_date )
```

3) Table level (the following example is not yet supported in SQL Server):

```
CHECK ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                       FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ProductID ) AS Tally
                                FROM Products AS P ) AS DT1 
                      WHERE Tally > 1 ) )
```

4) Database level (not yet supported in SQL Server):

```
CREATE ASSERTION EnterpriseUniqueIds
   CHECK ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                          FROM ProductID AS P
                               JOIN Components AS C
                                  ON C.ComponentID = P.ProductID ) );
```

---

A key constraint involves comparing different rows within the same table, therefore it is a table-level constraint.

Comment: At least in 2016 it is somewhat supported via [functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258).

Comment: @PavelVoronin: using a function in this way has been [problematic historically](https://web.archive.org/web/20100507204302/http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/02/19/Trouble-with-CHECK-Constraints.aspx). Have they fixed it in 2016?

Comment: Had no chance to check this scenario, yet I tried  mine on 2014 server. By 2016 I meant a year =)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but FYI for others

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13744.table-level-vs-column-level-constraints.aspx

Comment: It would be better if you could post the content here and then mention the source with the link. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to define  constraints one is at column level and the other is at table level.one can use any of these methods to apply constrains.