# ERROR Column CHECK constraint for column references another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I use MS SQL 2008 R2, I need create a Table with a CHECK on a specific column but I receive this error. Could you please point me out in the right direction? Thanks

```
HeatingSystem   tinyint             NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT  CK_ReProperties_HeatingSystem   CHECK(Size between 0 and 3),
```

**ERROR**

Msg 8141, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Column CHECK constraint for column 'HeatingSystem' references another column, table 'ReProperties'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: What do you wanna achieve ? The HeatingSystem must be 0 if Size is not between 0 and 3 ?

Comment: I would like limit the possible valuse for HeatingSystem so HeatingSystem should accept only 0, 1, 2, 3

Comment: If you just put a comma after NOT NULL, that would make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your comment, I don't understand where "Size" is coming from...

Can't you just make

```
CONSTRAINT  CK_ReProperties_HeatingSystem   CHECK(HeatingSystem between 0 and 3)
```

Comment: @GibboK well, you just did it

Answer (score 13):

Constraints that are defined inline at column level can only reference the column they are defined next to.

Either move the constraint definition next to the correct column or move the constraint definition to the end of the table definition.

### Fails

```
CREATE TABLE HeatingSystem
(
Size INT,
HeatingSystem TINYINT CHECK(Size between 0 and 3)
)
```

### Succeeds

```
CREATE TABLE HeatingSystem
(
Size INT CHECK(Size between 0 and 3),
HeatingSystem TINYINT
)
```

### Also Succeeds

```
CREATE TABLE HeatingSystem
(
Size INT ,
HeatingSystem TINYINT,
CHECK(Size between 0 and 3 AND HeatingSystem BETWEEN 1 AND 10)
)
```

The final way also allows you to declare a [row level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9495030/73226) constraint referencing multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I have solved.

```
HeatingSystem   tinyint             NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT  CK_ReProperties_HeatingSystem   CHECK(HeatingSystem between 0 and 3),
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your query and it is giving me error as `Invalid column name 'Size'.` You should write the columnname - `HeatingSystem`    in place of `size`. Use the following:-

```
HeatingSystem   tinyint             NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT  CK_ReProperties_HeatingSystem   CHECK(HeatingSystem between 0 and 3),
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be just missing a comma separator before the word CONSTRAINT !!

e.g.) if "," after ([WorkLocationId]) in below snippet is missing then, it will throw ERROR Column CHECK constraint for column references another column error.

This will throw error -

```
CREATE TABLE [MYSYSTEM].[User](
[UserId] int Primary key NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[UserStatus] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
[CreatedDate] [Datetime] NOT NULL,
[WorkLocationId] int NOT NULL Foreign Key References [HRSYSTEM].[WorkLocations]([WorkLocationId])
CONSTRAINT [_UserStatusValues] CHECK ([UserStatus] IN ('A','I') )
)
```

This will work -

```
CREATE TABLE [MYSYSTEM].[User](
[UserId] int Primary key NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[UserStatus] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
[CreatedDate] [Datetime] NOT NULL,
[WorkLocationId] int NOT NULL Foreign Key References [HRSYSTEM].[WorkLocations]([WorkLocationId]),
CONSTRAINT [_UserStatusValues] CHECK ([UserStatus] IN ('A','I') )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a table level constraint, i.e move the constraint to the end of the table definition.